# Django - many to many forwards vs foreign keys backwards

Tags: sql, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Consider these 2 examples:

Example 1: model A > many to many > model B's

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    model_b = models.ManyToManyField('ModelB')
```

Example 2: model B > foreignkey > model A

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA')
```

Is there a reason to choose one over the other apart from requirements/personal preference?

Are there any important considerations relating to this choice?

Edit:
The foreign key doesn't allow modelB to have multiple modelA but for this example, let's suppose this isn't a requirement.

Comment: _let's suppose this isn't a requirement._ - then don't use, foriegnkey  is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you choose a ManyToManyField when you don't actually want a many-to-many relationship? Since they require a linking table, they are significantly less efficient than a ForeignKey which is a simple join between tables. Don't use them unless you actually need the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make that much difference whether you specify a many-to-many relationship on one table or the other given that the relationship is always represented by a third table.

You may wish to experiment with a few code samples to see if either representation appears to make your code more readable.